# BPEL editor for netbeans 8

Tags: netbeans-8, bpel

I am using `netbeans 8` and I need to use a `BPEL` editor. It seems that `SOA` plugin no longer exist for `netbeans 8`.
Any idea ? I don't like to install `Eclipse` (it is more practical to have one `Java IDE`).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of NetBeans after 6.5 dont have BPEL plugin.